# Making Billy's engine

Tags: happy-street

Does any one know how to complete the quest "The Engine" given by Billy? It is in the quest series to unlock the Mountain area.  I'm at the stage were I can't progress much without it. Everything I need for my street now needs rocks and I can't get them without the mountain gate. Please help!

Comment: @6sue6 Welcome to Arqade!  We play a lot of games here, so it's important to be clear about what game you are talking about.  I figured it out, and edited your question.  Hopefully it will get reopened shortly, so we can get you an answer - but in the future please try to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in this [forum post](http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-games/86192-happy-street-quests.html) you need the following things to complete "The Engine"

> - Magic Gem x1
> - Wood Plank x2
> - Glue x1

I presume because you have this quest that you already have the Magic Gem which was the quest reward from the previous quest "Family Heirloom" given by Pepin.  If not, you might heed this advice:

> The Magic Gem is a quest reward. You’ll need to craft one Black Lotus to trade to Pepin before you can complete “The Engine.” If you’re reading this and have yet to get this quest, I suggest you start crafting a Black Lotus before you go to bed.